# XamarinForms - Grid vs nested Stacklayouts - PERFORMANCE sweet spot

Tags: performance, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Considering **performance** - where is the sweet spot between grid and nested stacklayouts?

How many "levels of nesting" StackLayout makes it more efficient to use Grid?

Is the example below (3 levels of StackLayout nesting) good practice, or should one use Grid instead?

```xml
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label>...text...</Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label>...text...</Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label>...text...</Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label>...text...</Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I haven't got any `performance` stats but looking at that I would use a `Grid`. Firstly it is very complicated to read and work out what's going on, and secondly the key to performance is to reduce the amount of controls as much as possible. 8 x `stacklayouts` vs 1 x `grid` is a no brainer to me

Comment: @user1 You shouldn't be forgetting that StackLayout is a much simpler control than a Grid. In my opinion - the xaml parser has a more work compiling a single Grid than a single StackLayout, which could result in a much bigger assembly size. And considering the performance - it would be cool if somebody provided a benchmark table on this topic :)

Comment: I'd like to suggest you to read an [article](http://kent-boogaart.com/blog/jason-smith's-xamarin-forms-performance-tips)

Comment: @YehorHromadskyi I already read that, but my question's topic is mentioned only in a very general way. I need numbers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use Grid.
There's a lot of common mistakes we make when using `Xamarin.Forms`. Fortunately, I found [this article and video](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/deployment-testing/performance/) that help me a lot.
One of the points on it is exactly an advice about your question:

> don't attempt to reproduce the appearance of a specific layout by using combinations of other layouts

This is exemplified by `Grid` x nested `StackLayouts`.

I hope it helps you too.

Comment: just what I was looking for. thanx.